# How to reference a parent object (i.e; from root or stage)?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently playing around with some AS3 platform gaming, and trying to go with a cleaner object-based approach for platforms. In short, I'm trying to detect if the player object is colliding with platform - ala:

```
if (!player.hitTestObject(this)) {
    //player falls
}
```

However, the problem is in actually referencing the player object - the player is at the following location (from the stage); manager.player - wheras the platforms are at manager.level.foreground.

Is there any way to actually reference the player object from within the foreground object as listed above, without passing in a constructor from the player to each and every instance of the platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do

```
if (!this.parent.parent.player.hitTestObject(this)) {
    //player falls
}
```

but i strongly advise against this as it is extremely inflexible to changes, and cause a possible debugging nightmare:)

would it not be neater to let the manager handle the collisions between it's children?

Comment: I was considering this approach - but the problem is that to keep it any way clean, I'd have to dump every platform into an array, and cycle through the entire loop searching for collisions - and then manage the array's size and members as areas of the level are removed/added (as far as I know).

Comment: Well, you would have to cycle through them whether you put the collision checking in the platform class or the manager. You could write a short function that fills an array with the platforms that are possible to collide with, ie find platforms that have a position within a circle around your character with the velocity as a radius.  hittesting is expensive, checking x and y coordinates is not

Answer (score 1):

You can get a static reference to the place that the player object is created in. In that class, you basically return a reference to the player.